# Angular.js: How to load module after the app has initialized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The execution steps in angular that known by me is like this:

1. load defined modules.
2. initialize the injector.
3. compile the html inside the [ng-app] tag.

Then if i want to load module after these three steps,seems i'd have to execute these three steps again.But i don't know how to exactly do it :-(
Any good solutions?thanks very much!

PS:The 'module' i mentioned is defined by angular.module() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is create a new injector. When the current app is initialized, the module you wanna load will be useless in the current app.

You can do:

```
angular.injector(...)
```

An injector is also created using

```
var injector = angular.bootstrap()
```

So, what you really wanted to do (i guess) is manually bootstrap your app (not using ng-app):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    var injector = angular.bootstrap(...)
    ....
});
```

Note that a module is like the "main(){}" function from 'C'; a module just specify how your angular app would work.

Comment: hey,i'v tried what u said.it works seems well but occur this issue:"Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module textAngular due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filterProvider"

Comment: you need to add angular-sanitize.js and import ngSanitize, module('mymodule', ['ngSanitize'])

Comment: sanitize is required if you are using ng-bind-html, or something, but not with manual bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is well known for its Dependency Injection (DI).

Suppose you have an app called `todoApp`. In this app, maybe you want a `Login` feature. Also you might want to have a `dateTracker` that helps you track the dates for whatever reason in your `todoApp`. At the same time, you want some animation, so you would want to include `ngAnimate` into your app. Each of these, we call it as a `module`.

Now, obviously, your `todoApp` ***depends*** on `Login` and `dateTracker` and `ngAnimate`. It needs these three modules to function properly. So what you will do is you inject the three modules into your `todo` app.

For your `todo.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp',
     [
       //inject all your dependencies here
       'Login',
       'dateTracker',
       'ngAnimate' 
     ]);
```

Maybe you want to do some configuration upon bootstrapping, you can just do it with `.config`

```
 app.config([
 //your configurations here
 ]);
```

Now you need to define other modules.

For `Login.js` maybe you need a certain service to check users credentials and authenticate him

```
angular.module('Login',[])
.factory('LoginService',['$http',function($http){

 //do your webservice calling here

});
```

And forget not the `dateTracker` module.

```
angular.module('dateTracker',[]); // code something meaningful using this module
```

For `ngAnimate` you just need to include that script.

The point is, if you have defined your modules properly, and injected them as needed, you don't usually need to reload your modules (there might be exceptions). Or to be exact, if you design your app properly, you *usaully* don't need more than one `ng-app`. For the example illustrated above, all you need to do is have your html include the `todoApp` module **ONCE**:

```
<html ng-app = "todoApp">
```

and voila your other modules will be injected and loaded at the same time. That's the beauty of [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Here is a [simple plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwlhIvIsSO7JChHd9Qh4?p=preview)

Maybe I have misunderstand your question or you specifically design to load other modules after an app has been bootstrapped, else I think you should really load all your modules ONCE and inject them for usage as per needed.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh,do u mean if i dont inject the specific module,then it wont be loaded to the page?

Comment: and how to inject it btw? sory, i am a noob :(

Comment: Have already demonstrated to you. Edited the answer with plnkr. Do note this is just a very simple demo on illustrating how to use Dependency Injection. Do read up on the original document

Comment: thank you very much.but i'v tried what you told to me,doesnt work,the module will load automaticlly whether you inject it.

Comment: Did you link up all your javascript files?

Comment: what do u mean by link up?

Comment: include all the javascript files. for example `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Comment: well, i think the only solution is to use multiple ng-app tag :) .thanks very much anyway, i love u